# Micronaut not initialising the singletons with war bundle in a tomact server

Tags: tomcat, micronaut

I am using micronaut application and I am trying to eager initialise the singletons on startup. Her e is the main code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.
                build(args)
                .eagerInitConfiguration(true)
                .eagerInitSingletons(true)
                .mainClass(App.class)
                .start();
    }
```

The above code works when I start the application using gradle run command. It initialises all the Beans which are marked @Singleton (jakarta.inject.Singleton).
`./gradlew run`

When I create a war file, and deploy this by copying a war file in the /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war, by running the tomact server. The Micronaut Apps doesn't seem to pick the configuration to initialises the singleton beans.

Is there any extra configuration required to pick and configure the eagerInitSingletons property when the application is initialised by Tomcat.

Comment: Have you followed this for Tomcat: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-servlet/latest/guide/#tomcat